# MS Access query custom function accepting form text input as value

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

G'day, everyone.

I've been banging my head against this question the whole day through today, and I haven't managed to find any answers, so I'd appreciate your help.

What I have:

- An Access form containing a text field
- A query which is the form's data source
- A custom function called RegExp defined within a module

RegExp takes two values as input: string (obtained from a table) and pattern (obtained from the form). RegExp returns a boolean value which in turn thins out query results.

The function works perfectly fine and as expected, however, this is only the case when the user fills out the text field. If the field is left blank, no results are returned (and the function's not even getting called if that's the case).

So here's what that particular statement within the query looks like:

```
... AND (RegExp(tblRole.Description,Trim([Forms]![frmFindRole]![txtRegExp]))<>False) AND ...
```

(Basically, to sum it up, user types in a value into the text field which gets leading and trailing spaces trimmed off, converted to a regular expression inside a VBA module, and then query results get filtered based on what boolean value the function returns).

There is a number of controls on this form, and they worked prior to me adding that txtRegExp text field. Now the query only returns results if txtRegExp is filled out, and I have no idea why. I've tried adding more checks, but the query's too complicated already, and I haven't succeeded.

If additional code samples are required for an answer to be made, I'll be able to provide them tomorrow.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. Would [Nz](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) help? If yes, then how would I go about using it?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the RegExp function to see if the function is entered when the textbox is empty and then go step by step to undertand what your function returns. Its possible that your function returns a NULL and that you end up with `NULL<>false` which is not a valid expression. NULL can't be compared to anything, that's why we always state `something IS NULL` and not `something = NULL`. For the NZ yes if my deduction is valid it can help indeed, like this : `AND (NZ(RegExp(tblRole.Description,Trim([Forms]![frmFindRole]![txtRegExp])),false)<>False) AND `

Comment: @Thomas, the function results in "Exit Function" if the second parameter (pattern = txtRegExp) is null. I've already tried playing with it (like setting pattern = True if IsNull(pattern); and I've put 4 different message boxes inside the function at different breakpoints, and the function doesn't fire **at all** if txtRegExp is blank ("and the function's not even getting called if that's the case"). I'm not sure if using breakpoints is any different compared to MsgBox, but that's what I've done.

Comment: There are multiple ways to fix this. How is the query triggered? Do you have a button or it is another event ? A solution would be to add a check there, if the textbox is empty you change the query to something else. Its difficult to provide a clear answer with what you have shown

Comment: @Thomas, I apologise if I'm a bit vague, I just don't have the code in front of me at the moment. What information would help you answer this question? The query is the data source (am I using the right term? it's a predefined query "attached" to the form - it's not inside VBA code) for the form. Every time a KeyUp event is triggered by any of the form's fields, a `.Requery` is performed. All other fields worked perfectly fine (I have to mention they are dropdowns, not text fields), it's the text input that behaves differently and kicks the other ones out of line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the few explanations you gave in comments

Suppose that this is code triggered on the KeyUp event :

```vb
Private Sub Form_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    Me.Requery

End Sub
```

Store the default SQL for your form's recordsource somewhere in a local variable. In this example I considered that you stored it in `SQLdefault` string.

Prior to requery, check if the textbox is empty and if yes change your form's recordsource SQL accordingly:

```vb
private SQLdefault as string

Private Sub Form_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    Dim SQL As String

    If Nz(txtRegExp, "") = "" Then
        SQL = SQLdefault 
        SQL = Replace(SQL, "AND (RegExp(tblRole.Description,Trim([Forms]![frmFindRole]![txtRegExp]))<>False)", "")
        Me.RecordSource = SQL ' Normally this is enought to requery, if not uncomment below
        'Me.Requery
    Else
        Me.RecordSource = SQLdefault ' Normally this is enought to requery, if not uncomment below
        ' Me.Requery
    End If

End Sub
```

In this example I just remove the SQL part containning :

```
AND (RegExp(tblRole.Description,Trim([Forms]![frmFindRole]![txtRegExp]))<>False)
```

Replace it by something else if that's not correct.

That's obviously not the most elegant solution but it's difficult to provide with the best solution with what you've shown.

Comment: 1) [The RegExp function](http://pastebin.com/yGb9c54s), 2) [The query](http://pastebin.com/jR7Vq37d) (it's a separate Access query, not a VBA string). The txtRegExp After Update function is a simple `.Requery`, nothing fancy. Same `.Requery` works fine for the other inputs. Were my query a string in VBA, I would've taken the `Replace` path as well. Unfortunately, it is not. Hopefully, this time there's enough data to work with. Thank you.

Comment: I've fixed it differently, but I'll mark your response as the answer, because it works as well, and because you've helped me immensely. Still not sure why the hell that function didn't fire on an empty input field value.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work by modifying my [initial query](http://pastebin.com/jR7Vq37d) to [include a check](http://pastebin.com/zCZ9ErAD) for the value of txtRegExp.

I am still not entirely sure why it failed with a blank txtRegExp value. I have a feeling the RegExp function somehow didn't fire when provided with NULL as the second parameter.

I am very grateful to [Thomas G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4197505/thomas-g) for all the help he's provided.